# Notes of identical pitch on the same beat

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music

In this measure of music from a piano accompaniment for Les Mis, This measure confuses me:[image: The measure in question] On the third beat, There is an F played with two rhythms, a dotted eighth note as well as a sixteenth note, I would expect the notes to overlap completely, and just play the F while holding it and letting it ring out while playing the following notes, is this the right interpretation, or did the arranger notate it this way because they actually wanted the F to be played twice?

Comment: You have the correct interpretation. It's arranged this way so it's clear that one voice  had a sixteenth and the other a dotted eighth. Were the note heads to overlap as in other similar circumstances, the sixteenth would appear to be a dotted sixteenth.

Comment: It's common to see this as a _single_ note head with two different stems and flags for the two different rhythms.